# How to generate Angular App shell in an integrated Nx monorepo workspace?

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-monorepo

I think the question is self-explanatory... Is there a way to generate Angular App shell in an integrated Nx monorepo workspace?

I know that if we call, let's say, `nx g @nx/angular:service my-service --project=lib-name`, because we're trying to invoke a generator that is not present in `@nx/angular`, the request will automatically be forwarded to `@schematics/angular`.

But generating an App shell in Angular is completely different! So I was wondering, is there a solution to this that I'm missing out here?

Thanks a heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although it seems that generating an App shell is different, but it's not!
When generating an App shell, we don't pass a name option... So we don't also need to pass a name when calling the command via Nx.

So here's what we need to run: `nx g @nx/angular:app-shell --project=app-name` This command actually fallbacks to `@schematics/angular` without any issues.

And then build the production files by running: `nx run app-name:app-shell:production`